# Are there any databases that properly support sum types/tagged unions?

Tags: database-recommendation

I want to model various different events. Every event happens at a specific time, but other than that, each event needs to have different associated data, depending on the type of event. In Rust, I can easily model this using a sum type (or tagged union if you will):

```rust
// Pretend these aren't empty...
struct Datetime;
struct Place;

struct Event {
    datetime: Datetime,
    kind: EventKind,
}

enum EventKind {
    Birth {
        place: Place,
        // Could have additional data, for example to signify if it was a C-section.
    },
    NameChange {
        new_name: String,
    },
    Death {
        place: Place,
        // Could have additional data, for example to signify cause of death.
    },
    // There might be more variants...
}
```

These are just some examples. There could be a lot more events with other kinds of associated data. I would want the system to be able to be expanded in the future with more kinds of events, with arbitrary associated data.

I'm looking for a database that can handle this kind of data in a proper way. Specifically, it should ensure that a certain kind of event always has the required associated data. It should also make it easy to query all events simultaneously, to iterate over all the various events without having to do multiple queries. Basically in order to deserialize whatever format the database stores the data in to the `Event` struct in Rust.

Are there any production-grade databases that can do this? I've thought about trying to model this with SQL, but [you need to jump through all kinds of hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730665/how-to-emulate-tagged-union-in-a-database) to make it work and even then it's not easy to, for instance, iterate over all events in a single query.

PostgreSQL has an inheritance feature which at first sounds a little promising, but inheritance is not the same as a sumtype and [there are caveats with using PostgreSQL inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-inherit.html#DDL-INHERIT-CAVEATS).

I've thought about NoSQL JSON-based databases. I don't have a lot of experience with these, so I can't comment too much, but my fear is that it would be hard to statically guarantee that an event always has the associated data (and nothing more) since the data is inherently unstructured in such databases (as far as I understand).

Are there any databases or methods that support this kind of data "natively"?

Comment: Never heard the term `sumtype`, and I'm not really understanding your example unfortunately, maybe you could elaborate with a couple more examples? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "*iterate over all events in a single query*" but iteration should rarely / never be needed with a properly architected relational database. Most modern relational databases offer JSON features and data types. If the associated data is unstructured and doesn't need relational integrity, then that's an option.

Comment: Not sure why you think it's a "hack" to use polymorphic association. It models your design pretty well. Why is it "not easy to, for instance, iterate over all events in a single query"?

Comment: @J.D. A sum type is a type that can be one of several variants. I.e. as opposed to a product type. They're usually implemented using [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union). Let's say I don't want to iterate over all events, but all events that happened in a certain time range, or maybe all `Birth` and `Death` events associated with a specific person.
The data is not unstructured and definitely needs relational integrity.

Comment: @Charlieface Because inheritance is not the same as a sum type and is a poor substitute for it. For instance, with PostgreSQL table inheritance, it's possible to make an event that is not present in any of the specific inherited sub-tables, which is nonsense (i.e. it's an event that doesn't correspond to any of the variants in the Rust enum).

Comment: You need a `Type` column, which is of the enum type (or has a check constraint) and use that as part of the PK/FFK relationshiip. Still doesn't prevent you having a missing subtype row, but you could use a deferrable constraint for that in Postgres